# how to write unreadable ^A into output file in Python?

Tags: python, file

Wondering how to write unreadable ^A into a file using Python. For unreadable ^A, I mean when we use command "set list" in vi, we can see unreadable character like ^I for '\t', $ for '\n'.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the character code, you can output it using the `chr()` function.  For example:

```
>>> chr(97)
'a'
```

Do you mean the [Start of Header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character?

[image]

If so, then use this:

```
chr(1)
```

Comment: I'm 90% sure SOH stands for "Start of Heading", not "Start of Header", but… Wikipedia clearly says "Header", and I'm too lazy to look further, so OK. :)

Comment: Yes, dana, I mean Start of Header. Your code works for me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is '\1'. Cheers!

Comment: Interesting... Ya, that works too: `print "\1" == chr(1)` returns `True`.

Comment: I find that `u'\u0001'.encode('cp861')` gives your code a nice Icelandic feel.